# Why am getting the error `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3, php-7

for the beolw code, am getting the warning - `require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\abcd\application\controllers/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. I've no idea why this error comes here, becoz the `autoload.php` file exists in `vendor` folder.And the folder is existing in the root directory.`composer_autoload` is `true` in `config\autoload.php`. Can someone tell me the possible causes of this issue?Anyhelp is much appreciated.

**controller**

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//require_once __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php'; //also tried reversing the slashes like this

class Reports extends Layout_Controller
{

}
```

[image: vendor\autoload.php]

composer install error

[image]

Comment: `Composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` try this one
if it's not working means remove vendor file and do `composer install`

Comment: @SaiTarun tried both. `Composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`  run successfully but my error is same. I couldn't run `composer install`  ,it shown some errors. Please the updated quetion

Comment: @SaiTarun can you please tell why the salshes before vendor & autoload is opposite in this line `require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\abcd\application\controllers/vendor/autoload.php)` .I think that is where am wrong

Comment: @user17189691 no, it's fine like that

Comment: PHP says there is no such a file, so there has to be something wrong with path... run `if(file_exists('C:/xampp/htdocs/abcd/application/controllers/vendor/autoload.php')) echo "file exists!";` or `menu start > cmd.exe` and type `cd C:/xampp/htdocs/abcd/application/controllers/vendor` then `dir`, is autoload.php there or not?

Comment: Can you add the full stack-trace to your question?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using unix based directory seperators on Windows.
I suggest you to use the php constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`:

```
...
require_once implode([__DIR__, 'composer', 'autoload_real.php'], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

This was automatically generated by composer so you can also run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

in Windows to generate it with the correct Windows style paths.

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

Comment: where should i give this line? in venodr\autoload.php? `require_once implode([__DIR__, 'composer', 'autoload_real.php'], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`

Comment: i tried `composer dump-autoload` , it didn't generated `require_once implode([__DIR__, 'composer', 'autoload_real.php'], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);` although it shown the success messages `generating autoload files`, `generated autoload fles`

Comment: Yes in line 5 of your screenshot, but most likely you will encounter similar issues down the line. Probably the easiest solution is to install Composer in Windows and run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Did you have the same error or a different one?

Comment: sholud i remove the line 7 from it?

Comment: i've the same error

Comment: the line `require_once implode([__DIR__, 'composer', 'autoload_real.php'], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);` in ur answer has `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` .do i need to define the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`?

Comment: can you please tell why the salshes before vendor & autoload is opposite in this line `require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\abcd\application\controllers/vendor/autoload.php)`.I think that is where am wrong

Comment: it's not a problem, you can use both on Windows and even mix them

Comment: @FlashThunder ok.Then,what can be wrong about my project?

Comment: the file doesn't exist, that's the only reason, the path is wrong, did you check that and you are 100% sure that the file is in the given path? it can't be that PHP returns `file not found` when the file is there... simply impossible. Another way to check it is to open notepad and open a file ... copy paste `C:\xampp\htdocs\abcd\application\controllers\vendor\autoload.php` to the open file dialog. If it will say it doesn't exist, it doesn't. Not sure about codeigniter, but normally vendors is not in controllers, but in main.

Comment: this has worked for me. Thanks bud

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `require_once __DIR__ . '../../vendor/autoload.php';` , edited @Mark's answer as follows

```
require_once implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [__DIR__, 'vendor/composer', 'vendor/autoload.php']);
```

and it worked!